# How to use bind_param for deleting from the database?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have the following method that inserts data to a table I have in my database

```
function database_preparedModify($sql, $types, &$insertId, ...$value)
  {
      $statement =  mysqli_prepare(database_link(), $sql);

      $statement->bind_param($types, ...$value);

      $statement->execute();

      $insertId = $statement->insert_id;

      return $statement->affected_rows;
  }
```

A valid use of this function (which works fine) is the following:

```
private function saveError(someError $error)
    {
        $sql = 'INSERT INTO stackoverflowErrors (dateTimeTest, errorURL, clientInfo, accountID, actions, message) 
                VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';
        $insertId = 0;
        database_preparedModify($sql, 'ssssss', $insertId, $error->getTime(), $error->errorURL(), $error->getClientInfo(), $error->getAccountID(), $error->getAction(), $error->getMessage());
    }
```

Where the methods `getTime()`, `errorURL()`...etc are in another class and not really relevant for this question.

My question is, how could I use the method `database_preparedModify()` to delete from the database instead of inserting? I've tried the following:

```
$filename = 'some valid filename';
$feed["id"] = $validID;
$insertId = 0;
$sql = "DELETE FROM `".$config_databaseTablePrefix."table1` WHERE filename = '".database_safe($filename)."'";

        database_preparedModify($sql,'s',$insertId, ' ');

$sql = "DELETE FROM `".$config_databaseTablePrefix."table2` WHERE id = '".database_safe($feed["id"])."'";

        database_preparedModify($sql,'s',$insertId, ' ');
```

But I'm getting this error:

> Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement

Comment: @Jay I'd like to invite you to consider lifting your hammer this one time.  This is a well-constructed question which includes an error message.  Certainly a better than average question.  The question is not about understanding the error.  It is asking how to refactor the existing method to achieve extended functionality.  Don't get me wrong, I think we need more hammerers, but please give this page a slow read and a second judgment.

Comment: After a second read I second what you have said here @mickmackusa - dupe close lifted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use placeholders in your query.

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM `".$config_databaseTablePrefix."table1` WHERE filename = ?";
database_preparedModify($sql,'s',$insertId, $filename);
```

and

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM `".$config_databaseTablePrefix."table2` WHERE id = ?";
database_preparedModify($sql,'s',$insertId, $feed["id"]);
```